# MWAA: Trouble installing Airflow Google Providers from requirements.txt

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, etl, mwaa

I'm trying to set up an MWAA Airflow 2.0 environment that integrates S3 and GCP's Pub/Sub. While we have no problems with the environment being initialized, we're having trouble installing some dependencies and importing Python packages -- specifically **apache-airflow-providers-google==2.2.0**.

We've followed all of the instructions based on the [official MWAA Python documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/working-dags-dependencies.html). We already included the [constraints file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.0.2/constraints-3.7.txt) as prescribed by AWS, activated all Airflow logging configs, and tested the requirements.txt file using the [MWAA local runner](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner). [The result when updating our MWAA environment's requirements would always be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1PTW.png)

When testing using the [MWAA local runner](https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner), we observed that using the requirements.txt file with the constraints still takes forever to resolve. [Installation takes more than 10-30 minutes which is no good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTz3U.jpg).

As an experiment, we tried using a version of the requirements.txt file that omits the constraints and pinned versioning. Doing so installs the packages successfully and we don't receive import errors anymore on both MWAA local runner and our MWAA environment itself. [However, all of our dags will fail to run no matter what. Airflow logs are also inaccessible whenever we do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdGj3.jpg).

The team and I have been trying to get MWAA environments up and running for our different applications and ETL pipelines but we just can't seem to get things to work smoothly. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problems and in the end we had to refactor a lot of things to remove the dependence. It looks like is a problem with PIP resolver and apache-airflow-providers-google if you look the official page:

https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/2.0.0rc1/

In the WORST case, you may need to use Airflow direct on EC2 from docker image and abandon MWAA :(

Comment: Apologies for the late response but thank you @FelipeFarias! We were unfortunately not able to continue using the google provider packages. You're right, we also had to refactor a lot of things given the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through similar issues but with different packages. There are certain things you need to take into consideration when using MWAA. I didn't have any issue testing the packages on the local runner then on MWAA using a public VPC, I only had issues when using a private VPC as the web server doesn't have an internet connection, so the method to get the packages to MWAA is different.

Things to take into consideration:

- The version of the packages; test on the local runner if you can first
- Enable the logs; The scheduler and web server logs can show you issues, but also they may not. The reason for this is Fargate serving the images, will try to roll back to a working state rather than have MWAA be in a non-working state. So, you might not see what the error actually is, it may even look like there were no errors in certain scenarios.
- Check dependencies; You may need to download a package with `pip download <package>==version`. There you can inspect the contents of the .whl file and see if there are any dependencies. You may have extra notes that can point you in the right direction. In one case, using the Slack package wouldn't work until I also added the http package, even though Airflow includes this package.

So, yes it's serverless, and you may have an easy time installing/setting MWAA up, but be prepared to do a little investigation if it doesn't work. I did contact AWS support, but managed to solve it myself in the end. Other than trying the obvious things, only those that use MWAA frequently and have faced varying scenarios will be of any assistance.